# Get all keys of a JObject that meet a certain criteria in vb.net

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, linq

I have a json file that I deserialize into a jObject. I need to find all fields that start with "DB", so that I can adjust these fields according to their respective names. The JObject looks like this:

```
 {
    "page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "db001": "text",
                "db002": "text",
                "db003": {
                    "item_1": "xxx",
                    "item_2": "xxx",
                    "item_3": "xxx"
                },
                "db004": "text",
                "db005": "text",
                "db006": "text",
            }
     ]
}
```

An example code which I was thinking was something along the lines of...

```
for each field in jObject.Where(function (f) f.StartsWith("DB"))
```

However, type JObject throws an error saying *".Where is not a member of newtonsoft.json.linq.jobject"*

I thought I could use a LINQ query to get all instances of these keys starting with "DB" or containing this syntax, but I'm struggling to find the right query.

Can someone point me the right way? I'm out of Google searches at this point...

Comment: Do you mean, e.g., `dim dbData = JObject.Parse(json)("data").First.Where(Function(jp) CType(jp, JProperty).Name.StartsWith("db")).ToArray()`?

Comment: Well, that worked!